# Android notification behavior

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an app that among other things has a built in messaging system. (So it's not sms, email and so on). I use a database (local and remote) to hold messages between users, and a syncAdapter makes sure to sync records from local to remote and viceversa.

Inside the syncAdapter I also show a notification when a new message arrives on my tablet.
I use this code to generate it:

```
String text_notificare_titlu = "Message from " + self.getSursanume();
String text_notificare_continut = self.getTitlu();
final NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.new_50, "New message for my app!", System.currentTimeMillis());
note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
note.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
// This pending intent will open after notification click
PendingIntent xx = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, i, new Intent(context, MesajeActivity.class), 0);
note.setLatestEventInfo(context, text_notificare_titlu, text_notificare_continut, xx);
note.number = i;
mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
```

Now, my problems:

1. The Autocancel does not work. When I click on the notification I
   want the notification to disappear after launching the intent but it does not
2. I want my intent that is shown on notification click to be a specific one (the one that holds the INBOX), so the MesajeActivity.class. It does appear, but if my app was minimized (hidden), when I click the notification, the new INBOX activity is shown ON TOP of the previous INBOX activity. It's like having 2 different activities on top of each other.
   So if :

   - my app is started, and the user is in the INBOX activity (MesajeActivity.class),
   - after a while the display shuts down,
   - when time comes, the syncAdapter fires,

     - finds a new message,
     - creates the notification,
   - the user clicks on the notification,
   - the INBOX activity is shown,
   - when I click BACK, the INBOX activity disappears and another INBOX activity shows up (the INBOX activity of the previously opened app).

Do you understand or should I try to explain better?

How can I solve these 2 problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am slightly unsure what exactly you meant by the second part. But, for your pending intent try this, PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, i, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
i.e. Replace 0 with the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

If that doesn't solve the problem, add the launchMode line to your MessageActivity declaration in the Manifest file like below. 
 android:launchMode="singleTask"

You can refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html for more info on singleTask

Comment: Wonderful, now it works perfectly. You understood correctly, and the second solution that you gave me worked. Now the notification-click updates the MessagesActivity that is being displayed. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

if you put

```
note.flags|= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

before `mgr.notify` call that should make the notification disappear when you click on it.

Comment: You seem to be right I think... at first I thought you did not see my code, only later I realised you were talking about a different thing. I had in my code `note.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;` and you suggested `note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`. Any idea on my other question?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my code that builds the notification with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MesajeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, i, intent, 0); 
        // Build notification
        // Actions are just fake
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Message from "+ self.getSursanume())
                .setContentText(self.getTitlu()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_50)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.new_50, self.getTitlucont(), pIntent)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        noti.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.htc4);
        noti.number = i;
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Now, it auto-cancels. It seems that I did not set the flag corectly. I did it for noti.defaults ?!?!? instead of noti.flags
However, my question number 2 is still in the air.

What to do to have only one MessajeActivity displayed?